# "The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available"

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I wanted to update packages on my 22.04 system but unfortunately I received this error:

```
sudo apt-get update

Err:5 https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all InRelease   
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BAC6F0C353D04109 
Fetched 4,451 B in 0s (9,069 B/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BAC6F0C353D04109 
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi/dists/all/InRelease  
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY BAC6F0C353D04109 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why is this/what is the solution?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys BAC6F0C353D04109
```

I don't really use the package in question (in case uninstalling is the easiest way).

Please assume I know very little.

Comment: Did you follow https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-linux/2023-0/apt.html to add this repo?

Comment: @muru Hi, thank you. Please put as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository which errors for you serves Intel's OneAPI Toolkit for Linux, it provides developer tools for AI, IoT, HPC (High Performance Computing) etc. As with any added repository to your system signatures need to be added also (that's the GPG / pgp). I had your exact problem, I think the signature might have expired and needed an update.

I repeated Step 3's two instructions of the https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/oneapi/installation-guide-linux/2023-0/apt.html page:

```
# download the key to system keyring
wget -O- https://apt.repos.intel.com/intel-gpg-keys/GPG-PUB-KEY-INTEL-SW-PRODUCTS.PUB | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/oneapi-archive-keyring.gpg > /dev/null

# add signed entry to apt sources and configure the APT client to use Intel repository:
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oneapi-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oneAPI.list
```

After that `apt update` didn't throw any errors on my system. Upgrading these packages may require 11GB+ free space, so keep that in mind!